# How do non-periodically varying currents produce electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform, radiation

Electromagnetic radiation is created by the varying/accelerating of a system of charges and currents. Suppose that the time dependence of the charges and currents are $\rho(x,t)$ and $J(x,t)$. Then the subsequent radiation will have the same time dependence. In Jackson it is stated that we can assume $\rho$ and $J$ have harmonic time dependence because we can build up any "arbitrary" function as a superposition of sinusoidal functions via Fourier analysis. My understanding of Fourier series is that we can only do this for periodic functions. We always refer to electromagnetic radiation as a wave because of the harmonic time dependence but the radiation has the same time dependence as $\rho(x,t)$ and $J(x,t)$. So what do we do, if the charges and currents are accelerating but not periodically? Then the electromagnetic radiation would not be a wave I think. So why does Jackson state that we can assume harmonic time dependence without losing any generality?

Comment: It would be a wave, and satisfying the wave equation moving with velocity c, it just wouldn't be sinusoidal.

Comment: @jensenpaull How would it be periodic if the varying charges and currents which generate it do not have periodic time dependence?

Comment: @JosephSanders The solutions of the wave equation aren't required to be periodic.

Comment: If the acceleration is not periodic, you can always do the analog of making a Fourier series, which is making a Fourier *integral*, i.e., a Fourier transform.  That is, instead of summing over a set of discrete frequencies, you sum over a *all possible* frequencies.

Comment: @Triatticus Thank you I somehow completely forgot that.

Comment: @march okay thank you!

Comment: See :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential  and 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula

Comment: From the mathematical point of view, searching for solutions in harmonic form means that we apply a Fourier transform to the equation and then we get a solution in Fourier domain. Basically if $\rho$ and $J$ are the function of t in a general sense, you can apply a Fourier Transform  to get $\rho(x, \omega)$ and $J(x,\omega)$ and then to multiply it by the transfer function of the system (the one you get when calculating with harmonic functions) and finally reapplying inverse Fourier transform.

Comment: To sum up, you can start from the "harmonic solution" and then recalculate a solution for any time dependence

Comment: @PierrePolovodov That makes more sense, thank you!

Comment: @PierrePolovodov I’m sorry to spam you but I was just thinking about i again and I’m not sure what you mean by transfer function!

Comment: No worries @JosephSanders, check this out https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Industrial_and_Systems_Engineering/Book%3A_Introduction_to_Control_Systems_(Iqbal)/02%3A_Transfer_Function_Models

Comment: and this http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/books/AM08/pdf/am08-complete_22Feb09.pdf

Comment: the last reference is page 2-5 (there is weird page ref in the book)

Comment: It is a bit math heavy though

Comment: Transfer funciton is a math concept to solve diff equation which is used in systems: control, feedback and filters etc

Comment: It simplifies the solution of these equations, instead of having derivative, one has polynomials

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fourier analysis does not require periodicity. This was one of the things about Fourier's work that shocked mathematicians. Essentially, any function you can graph may be decomposed into sinusoidal waves.

Imagine electric field lines converging at a charge in a particular position. Now, move that charge to a new position. The electric field lines will converge at the new position. But the news that you've moved the charge can't travel faster than the speed of light. So, there's a kink in the lines joining the old lines with the new.

It turns out that that kink moves at the speed of light. It's a non-periodic electromagnetic wave.

Answer (score 11):

The confusion is between [*Fourier series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), which is expansion for periodic functions, and [*Fourier transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) - which  is an expansion for arbitrary functions (satisfying certain mathematical conditions.)

Fourier transform can be though of as a generalization of Fourier series. Some would probably even say that Fourier series simply a particular case of the Fourier transform, although certain care is required when switching from one to another.

Finally, it is mentioning a useful trick: a function defined in an interval, can be extended periodically beyond this interval and expanded in Fourier series.

Since Maxwell equations are linear equations, we can Fourier transform the sources (currents and charges) and the fields, and solve the equation in Fourier space. Thus, even non-periodic fields can be represented in terms of periodic waves.

A related topic is the electromagnetic field radiated by an accelerated point charge: see [Liénard-Wiechert potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) and [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula).